# Tips how to draw circle with logo and lines

Tags: gimp

I'm a complete noob in graphics. I would like to draw something similar to this:

[image]

I'm able to draw the circles but anything else is beyond my knowledge and Gimp is quite complex for me to understand. Can you advise me how to:

- do the shading around the circles?
- draw the lines that bends so nicely?
- center image of logo inside a circle?

Comment: I'd avise you to search for some basic Gimp tutorials then. Search for how to use the tools, how to draw a dotted line, drop shadows, round corners, object alignment, etc.

Comment: Typically you should be using vector graphics  for this, which means inkscape instead of Gimp. You can also look for the drawing component of office suites (LibreOffice Draw, for instance).

Comment: @Xenoid, I'm gonna have a look at InkScape. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use Gimp:

- Shadows: use [Drop shadow](https://docs.gimp.org/en/script-fu-drop-shadow.html)
- The lines are drawn with ["paths"](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-paths.html). For the round bends, you create circles are the right places and cut-off 3 quarters, and then splice the remaining bits with straight lines
- To center things there is the [Align tool](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-align.html). But a better way is to use [guides](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-image-guides.html) that intersect where you want the circle centers, you can then create the circles centered there, and when moving/dragging objects their center will snap to that position when you get close enough. Guide can also be use to help you draw the lines.

Steep learning curve, though.